# Ошибка(?) при запуске программы на java в cmd

Tags: java, строки, cmd

[image: Пети, Васи и Коли не обижайтесь.]

Здравствуйте. Решил запустить программу в cmd, а получились такие кроказябры. 
Объясните , пожалуйста, что это и с чем его едят (я только учусь,прошу тапками не кидать). Если вдруг как-нибудь поможет , 
то кодировка UTF-8.
P.s. Пети, Васи и Коли не обижайтесь.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
System.out.println(myPeople[i] + " нехороший человек")
```